# Changing the trace and file and line number in DevTools console.log

Tags: reactjs, console.log

In a react app, I have a hook that analyzes props. When a condition is met, it prints a message to the console.
**Is there a way to modify the file and line number in DevTools console.log output?**

I made a simple sandbox to illustrate it, however, it adds additional layer of abstraction so it is not 100% accurate.
https://codesandbox.io/s/console-change-file-line-number-7q97c6

Say I have a hook:

```
function usePrint(value: number) {
  console.log('log:', value)
  console.trace('trace:', value)
}
```

It is used in several components like this:

```
const First: React.FC<{value: number}> = ({value}) => {
  usePrint(value)
  return <span>{value}</span>
}
```

The problem is that whenever it prints, I get the `usePrint.ts` as source in the output in console:

```json
log: 1                                                              usePrint.ts:2
trace: 1                                                            usePrint.ts:3
        usePrint            @ usePrint.ts:3
        First               @ First.tsx:2
        ...dozen of more lines

log: 1                                                              usePrint.ts:2
trace: 1                                                            usePrint.ts:3
        usePrint            @ usePrint.ts:3
        Second              @ Second.tsx:2
        ...dozen of more lines
```

As you can see, the least I can do is to `console.trace` it to the original file:line that uses the hook, but it gives way too much information, making the experience even worse.

Is there a way to achieve anything that makes it a little more ergonomic?

- Ideally modify the console.log file:line on the right?

  ```json
  log: 1                                                            First.tsx:2
  ```
- Or trim the trace output to just one line?

  ```json
  trace: 1                                                        usePrint.ts:3
          First               @ First.tsx:2
  ```
- ... Or even create custom inline source link?

  ```json
  First.tsx:2 -> log: 1                                           usePrint.ts:2
  ```

---

PS:

The actual hook in question is this one [gist/ackvf#useDependencies](https://gist.github.com/ackvf/39049d109d2097c2b0c273190d0c391c).
Lines with console are 72 and 134.

[image]